# Struts 2 - inner Class how property

Tags: java, struts2

I have a class Entity inner other class(Entity too), this inner class have a property which I will use in my jsp.
When submit the form, i get the error

java.lang.InstantiationException: mylib.recursos.entidades.documento.EntidadFactura$ETipo

My class:

```
public class EntidadFactura 
{
EntidadFactura.ETipo tipo;

public ETipo getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}
public void setTipo(ETipo tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}
public class ETipo
{
    private String desTipo;

    public String getDesTipo() {
        return desTipo;
    }

    public void setDesTipo(String desTipo) {
        this.desTipo = desTipo;
    }

}
}
```

and my action class:

```
public class ControladorPrueba extends ActionSupport
{
private EntidadFactura factura;

public String acTestForm()
{
    factura=new EntidadFactura();
    EntidadFactura.ETipo tipo = new EntidadFactura().new ETipo();
    tipo.setDesTipo("another type");
    factura.setTipo(tipo);
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String acTestSave()
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Value:");
        System.out.println(factura.getTipo().getDesTipo());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Value Error");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
}
```

acTestForm show the form, and shows the value but when submit the form, i get the error:

java.lang.InstantiationException: mylib.recursos.entidades.documento.EntidadFactura$ETipo

this is my jsp:

```
<s:form action="testsave" theme="simple" namespace="/" >
    Tipo Factura<s:textfield name="factura.tipo.desTipo"/>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</s:form>
```

And I do not why. The property factura has its get and set (getFactura,setFactura).
I hope you can help me.

Thanks...

Comment: If you really want this class to be an inner class, it should at least be a `static` inner class. A non-static inner class needs an instance of its enclosing class to be constructed, and this implicit reference to the enclosing object is completely useless here. Once static, you'll be able to simply use `new ETipo()` to construct an instance. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html